# Probability of Sequentially Drawing Balls 1, 2, and 3 from an Urn Containing n Balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I'm new to probability theory. I'm trying to do some exercices as the one suggested below but I've come across a solution that I didn't quite understand. Can you, guys, help me figure this out?

> An urn contains $n$ balls numbered from 1 to $n$, where $n \geq 3$. Without replacement, we draw one ball at a time from this urn. All balls are indistinguishable by touch.
>
> What is the probability that balls 1, 2, and 3 are drawn consecutively and in that order?

I went like this:

First, I would like to point out that in this random experiment, the assumption of equiprobability is clearly satisfied because the balls are identical and indistinguishable by touch.

When we draw n balls one by one from an urn containing a total of n balls, the number of possible outcomes corresponds exactly to the number of combinations of n elements.
In other words: $\text{card}(\Omega) = n!$, where $\Omega$ is the set of all possible outcomes.

We have n-2 possible outcomes for the first ball to be ball number 1 since it cannot occupy the positions "$n-1$" and "$n$".

We have one possible outcome for the second ball to be ball number 2, following ball number 1.

We have one possible outcome for the third ball to be ball number 3, following ball number 2.

Therefore, the number of possible outcomes corresponding to obtaining balls 1, 2, and 3 in this consecutive order is $(n-2) \times 1 \times 1$.

Thus, the probability is equal to $\cfrac{n-2}{n!}$.

However, the suggested solution is that the probability is equal to $\cfrac{(n-2)(n-3)!}{n!}$ but there is no explanation why.

Comment: You want to count the arrangements of $\{1,\cdots, n\}$ where $1,2,3$ appear consecutively. If an arrangement is of this form, then as soon as you know where $3$ is, you know precisely where $1,2$ are, and there's no freedom in their placement. Of course, $3$ itself can appear anywhere (upto being preceded by $1,2)$. So, the total number of such arrangments is just the number of arrangements of $\{3,\cdots, n\},$ i.e., $(n-2)!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me just give an example.

Suppose $n=5$.

Then there are $5!=120$ possible orders and there are $3\times2!=6$ favorable orders:

- 12345
- 12354
- 41235
- 51234
- 45123
- 54123

Factor $3$ corresponds with the number of ways we can place string 123 and factor $2!$ with the number of ways we can order 4 and 5.